# Import Composer Project Into Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, composer-php

I'm trying to import a composer project into a plugin for wordpress. Is there a better way to do this than requiring every single asset? I do not plan to use composer to manage anything moving forward with this project, but I did use composer to install all requirements into the project folder (the plugin folder). Essentially, I'm trying to figure out how to convert a composer project to a wordpress plugin.

Comment: What else are you going to use to manage your vendors? Or you want to do it manually?

Comment: Maintenence can be done through composer or not, doesnt matter. All I'm looking for is a way to import every asset in the project to the wordpress loop in my plugin

Answer (score 0):

What you could do, load the autoloader from `vendor/autoloader.php` inside your `functions.php`. Then you could do something like this:

```
$loader = require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/vendor/autoload.php';
$loader->addPsr4('NAMESPACE\\', __DIR__ . '/app');
```

You are now autoloading the app folder.

Comment: So this is the approach I was hoping for, but it is returning the same error. Ive tried calling the ApiFactory class globally and namespaced as EXAMPLE\, with no success


`require_once(EXAMPLE_PLUGIN_PATH . 'vendor/autoload.php');
$loader = require EXAMPLE_PLUGIN_PATH . 'vendor/autoload.php';
$loader->addPsr4('EXAMPLE\\', EXAMPLE_PLUGIN_PATH);
$api = EXAMPLE\ApiFactory::create('exampledata');`

Comment: Why are you requiring the autoload twice? Just include it once in the main file of your plugin. Then register the autoloader with your namespace.

Answer (score 0):

#### How I use a composer packages into Wordpress plugin

1. I have a plugin's folder `wp-content/plugins/stack-overflow/`
2. Inside the folder I have the `composer.json` like next:

   ```
   {
       "name": "kumaxim/webhose-io-integration",
       "license": "proprietary",
       "authors": [
           {
             "name": "Your_name_here",
             "email": "your_email_if@your_want.com"
           }
         ],
       "require": {
           "php": "^5.4"
           *** you can add other packages here ***
     }
   }
   ```
3. You have a plugin's file like next:

   ```
   <?php
   /**
    * Plugin Name:       The name of the plugin
   */
   defined( 'WPINC' ) || die( 'Access restricted' );

   function your_prefix_plugin_run() {
       require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
   }

   your_prefix_plugin_run();
   ```

Pay attention, I strong recommend to call composer dependencies in plugin's bootstrap function. I have a problems in the past when I required it outside function.

### What is next?

Add your dependencies and run `composer install` or `composer update`